# Etherscan Get ERC20 Count of Address

Tags: etherscan, explorer-api

How do I get the count of an erc20 token e.g. KNC of an address via Etherscan API?

Or is there another API that can do that?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Such an API would require both the account address you want to query the balance for, as well as the address of the ERC-20 contract itself.

Such a service doesn't appear to be provided by Etherscan, in either their [Accounts](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) or [Tokens](https://etherscan.io/apis#tokens) API endpoint.

Instead you could have a look at a service like [TokenBalance](https://tokenbalance.com/), which provides the following endpoint for the main network:

```
https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/$CONTRACT/$ETH_ADDRESS
```

(Associated GitHub repo, [here](https://github.com/hunterlong/tokenbalance).)

There are probably other sites providing the same service.

**Edit:**

As an example, the below call queries the KNC contract (address: [`0xdd974d5c2e2928dea5f71b9825b8b646686bd200`](https://etherscan.io/token/KyberNetwork#balances)) for the balance of an address I picked from the [list of holding address](https://etherscan.io/token/KyberNetwork#balances).

```
 https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/0xdd974d5c2e2928dea5f71b9825b8b646686bd200/0x3eb01b3391ea15ce752d01cf3d3f09dec596f650
```

The output, in JSON format, is:

```
{
  "name": "Kyber Network Crystal",
  "wallet": "0x3eb01b3391ea15ce752d01cf3d3f09dec596f650",
  "symbol": "KNC",
  "balance": "81584601.83886412108548039",
  "eth_balance": "95011.193424973798190977",
  "decimals": 18,
  "block": 4651327
}
```

Comment: That tokenbalance API does not work for me

Comment: It works for me if I query the KNC token. I've edited the answer with this as an example. What error are you seeing?

Comment: do you know how to get the same information using JSON-RPC? thanks