# EtherScan API get erc20 token balance at specific block?

Tags: erc-20

I am trying to find a way to get the balance of erc20 token of any specific address at given block.
So far i succeeded in getting current balance but couldn't find a way to get it from the specific block using EtherScan API, is there a way?

I am using this to get current balance of specific ERC20 token,

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x57d90b64a1a57749b0f932f1a3395792e12e7055&address=0xe04f27eb70e025b78871a2ad7eabe85e61212761&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

Comment: There are several similar questions (with answers) to this question (or related) e.g. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/is-there-api-way-to-get-token-transfer-data-of-exact-token/42728#42728, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35166/etherscan-get-erc20-count-of-address